# Print last digit in Numpy Array

Tags: numpy, array

I'm sure this is pretty basic, but is there a way to print a certain indexed portion of each segment in an array? For example, if I have the numpy array:

([1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9])

I'd like to print out 3,6,9.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Access the last element using [-1] indexing.

```
x = numpy.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])
for i in x:
    print i[-1]
```

Comment: But that would just give me 7,8,9 right? I'm looking for 3,6,9.

Comment: No, the i[-1] simply gets the last element in a list. The for loop goes through each list in the array.

Comment: Oh I see. I can't believe I overlooked that. Thanks.